# Problems with installing a source package in R project with renv

Tags: r, renv

I experience a strange error in R: I have a package project (package A) with renv as a dependency tracker. One of dependencies of the package is another package (package B) that I need to install from source:

```
install.packages(<path to package B>, repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

But I get an error saying that 'There is no package `dplyr`'. It's strange because I see 'dplyr' is installed and it's in the renv's lockfile.
Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you provide any sort of minimal reproducible example we can use to re-create the error and provide possible solutions? What does your renv configuration look like? Are you using RStudio projects? What does the DESCRIPTION file for these packages look like? When exactly does the error pop up?